# error occured in the test class "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [RESTCaseController].createNewCase()"

Tags: apex

Here is my Apex class and its test class. There is an error i.e "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [RESTCaseController].createNewCase()"

Apex class is:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v2/setOrder/*')

global with sharing class RESTCaseController {


@HttpPost
global static String createNewCase(String product_id, String email, String name, String last_name, String phone,  String address, 
                                   String city, String state, String country, String zip, String shipping_address, String shipping_city, 
                                   String shipping_state, String shipping_zip, String shipping_country, String cc_number, String security_code,
                                   String cc_exp_month,  String cc_exp_year, String ip, String utm_source, String utm_medium, String utm_campaign,
                                   String utm_content, String utm_term, String sales_funnel_name, String landing_page_url, String referral_domain_url,
                                   String charge_date
                                  ){

    String accountId = '';                                       
    List<Account> anct = [SELECT Id from Account  WHERE PersonEmail   = :email];                                           

    /* If PersonAccount's record does not exist */               
    if(anct.size() == 0){ 

        Account ant = new Account();

        ant.FirstName = name;
        ant.LastName = last_name;
        ant.Phone = phone;
        ant.BillingStreet = address;
        ant.PersonEmail = email;

        /* Billing Info */
        ant.BillingStreet = address;
        ant.BillingCity = city; 
        ant.BillingStateCode = state;
        ant.BillingCountry = country;
        ant.BillingPostalCode = zip;            

         /* Shipping Info */
        ant.ShippingStreet = shipping_address;
        ant.ShippingCity = shipping_city;
        ant.ShippingStateCode = shipping_state;
        ant.ShippingCountry =  shipping_country;  
        ant.ShippingPostalCode = shipping_zip;

        /* Tracking Information */
        ant.utm_source__c = utm_source;
        ant.utm_medium__c = utm_medium;
        ant.utm_campaign__c = utm_campaign;
        ant.utm_content__c = utm_content;
        ant.utm_term__c = utm_term; 
        ant.sales_funnel_name__c = sales_funnel_name;
        ant.landing_page_url__c = landing_page_url;
        ant.referral_domain_url__c = referral_domain_url;



        insert ant;
        accountId = ant.id;

    }else{
   /* If PersonAccount's record already exist */                
        List<Account> actt = [SELECT Id from Account  WHERE PersonEmail   = :email];
        for(Account a: actt){
            accountId = a.Id;
        }
    }                              

    /* Save new ChargeNT Order */                                           
    ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c cOrder = new ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c();                            
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Account__c = accountId;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Bank_Account_Name__c = name;  

    /* Billing Info */                                  
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Address__c = address;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_City__c = city;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Country__c = country;    
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Email__c = email;                                       
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_First_Name__c = name;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Last_Name__c = last_name;                               
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Phone__c = phone;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_State__c = state;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Zip_Postal__c = zip;

    /* CC information */                                  
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Payment_Method__c = 'Credit Card';                                           
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Card_Type__c = 'Visa';                             
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Card_Expiration_Month__c = cc_exp_month;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Card_Expiration_Year__c = cc_exp_year;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Card_Number__c = cc_number;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Card_Security_Code__c = security_code;  

    /* Order Amount Infromation */                                  
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Charge_Amount__c = 2.00;                                           
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Tax__c = 1.00;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Subtotal__c = 2.00;                                           
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Currency__c = 'US Dollar';
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Charge_Date__c = charge_date; 
    Date presentDate = Date.Today();  
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Payment_Start_Date__c  = presentDate;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Payment_End_Date__c = presentDate;                               


    /* Shipping Info */                                  
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Address__c = shipping_address;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_City__c = shipping_city;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_State__c = shipping_state;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Country__c = shipping_country;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_First_Name__c = name;                                          
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Phone__c = phone;
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Zip_Postal__c = shipping_zip;

    /* Payment Gateway Info */        
    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Gateway__c = 'a02550000014Yz0';  

    /* Tracking Information */                                                  
    corder.utm_source__c = utm_source; 
    cOrder.utm_medium__c  = utm_medium;                                         
    cOrder.utm_campaign__c = utm_campaign;
    cOrder.utm_content__c = utm_content;
    cOrder.utm_term__c = utm_term;
    cOrder.sales_funnel_name__c = sales_funnel_name;                                               
    cOrder.landing_page_url__c = landing_page_url;   
    cOrder.referral_domain_url__c = referral_domain_url;

    cOrder.ChargentOrders__Customer_IP__c = ip;                                  
    insert cOrder;
    String test = 'dx_test';
    REST_ChargeNT_Controller ch = new REST_ChargeNT_Controller();                                          
    String res = ch.getCharge(test);                                  

    return res;               
}
}
```

and its test class is:

```
@isTest
public class RESTCaseController_Test {

static testMethod void testcreateNewCase(){ 
   RESTCaseController newcasetest = new RESTCaseController();
     String result = newcasetest.createNewCase();
}
}
```

Is someone can create the test class of my above apex class, so that it can be passed in both sandbox as well as production.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods do not require an instance of a class to be called. From external classes, instead you qualify the name with just the class name. You will also have to pass in all the values in the method signature.

So:

```
@isTest
public class RESTCaseController_Test {

    static testMethod void testcreateNewCase() {

        String result = RESTCaseController.createNewCase(...);
        ...
    }
}
```